# how to write information to sysfs from kernel?

Tags: android, linux, kernel, cat, sysfs

I am modifying and debugging the Linux Kernel about the schedule on multicore board. I need to check some information and I find the printk cost too much and the system can go wrong. So I try to send these information via sysfs. Then I can get this information from Android APP by using the "cat" command. However I did not find any tutorial to show how to send information to sysfs. How can I write information to sysfs from kernel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered looking at how existing sysfs files are implemented?

Comment: No. I know it is a RAM file system and the CPU information can be get from that and so I just think that may be a way to send more information.